# Redirect Traffic to "Site Down For Maintenance" Page - WordPress on Amazon EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress blog hosted on an Amazon EC2 microinstance. I created a child theme which I am currently using. Now that the site is live, I need to maintain it for a couple of hours every other day. My question is, how do I direct any users that may visit the site to a "Down For Maintenance" page in my child theme? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838019/approach-for-site-down-for-maintenance) which suggested altering the routes but this was specifically for Kohana. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry if this question is more appropriate for Server Fault, however, I was banned from SF for asking two questions that were down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/) plugin for your requirements. Enjoy!